# Styling the border of a QComboBox pop up

Tags: c++, css, qt, qcombobox

I'm trying to style the pop-up of a `QComboBox`.
Right now I have this pop-up:

[image: popup without border]

I want to give it a border, so I insert the following code in my `QComboBox` class:

```
QWidget* popUp = findChild<QFrame*>();
popUp->setStyleSheet("QWidget {border: 1px solid rgb(74, 74, 74);}");
```

which gives me this result:

[image: popup with border]

A pop-up with two borders: an internal one and an external one. And I only want the external one. Any ideas, thoughts or corrections?

Comment: The problem here is probably that with `"QWidget {border: 1px solid rgb(74, 74, 74);}"` you set a border for every QWidget. As you have multiple ones you get multiple borders. But that is a CSS problem ;)

Comment: Yet another same question... Take a look at https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/stylesheet-examples.html#id-bcbaea83-e720-403d-b175-7dc186b83ff1

Comment: is there any other qss that effects this popup? If it is, can you give some runnable code partition?

Comment: i am suspecting from padding issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Theolodis said, you just have to specify which QWidget you want to modify with your CSS.

`popUp->setStyleSheet("QWidget#popUp {border: 1px solid rgb(74, 74, 74);}");`